# angular form validation `min` not working

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-forms

I am reading https://angular.io/guide/forms.

My codes:

```
  <!-- Min price -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="minprice">Min price</label>
    <input type="number"
           min="0"
           class="form-control" id="minprice"
           required
           [(ngModel)]="model.minprice" name="minprice"
           #minprice="ngModel">
    <div [hidden]="minprice.valid"
         class="alert alert-danger">
      Min price is required
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Max price -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="maxprice">Min price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="maxprice"
           required
           min="0"
           [(ngModel)]="model.maxprice" name="maxprice"
           #maxprice="ngModel">
    <div [hidden]="maxprice.valid"
         class="alert alert-danger">
      Max price is required
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have two questions:

1, `min="0"` seems not working. when I input `-1`, no error message shown.

2, How to validate that `minprice` less than `maxprice`?

Any hints welcomed. Thanks

Comment: if you want custom validations you can add that on every formControl here is the method for that https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators

Comment: Seems like you are trying to check value, but min="0" actually check length of input not check what value you have passed.

Comment: @BAE, Added below working example.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `type="number"` your input control populates with up/down arrow to increment/decrement numeric value, so when you update textbox value with those buttons it will not pass max limit but when you manually give input it will not validate for max limit, so you have to validate it by code.

I will do it something like this if I am using `FormControlModule`:

```
 <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="MyInput" [formControl]="myInput">
```

And then in my component class:

```
this.myInput =  new FormControl("", [Validators.max(100), Validators.min(0)])
```

And then if you log `myInput` you will see a error key in the object which you can then use to show and hide the error message container.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what I really needed was not `Validators.min`, but `Validators.minLength`.

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **restart** VSCode. It might not help, but it might.

I've had some **wired experience**.

When I tried to use **Validators.min(1)** for the first time in my Angular project to stop the number field from going below 1, but it did NOT work.

No matter what I did, **Validators.min(1)** couldn't stop the number field from going below 1! If I kept clicking the down arrow of the number field, the number would keep going down to negative infinity.

So I tried **Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]+[1-9]*$/)**, and the number stopped going below 1.

Then I tried **Validators.min(1)** again, and this time the number didn't go below 1.

I restarted VSCode, and the number still didn't go below 1.

It was weird like that.

Answer (score 0):

Check min value instead of min length.

```
 // call additional check for value in html
 <div [hidden]="minprice.valid && checkMinValue(minprice)"
  class="alert alert-danger">
   Min price is required
</div>

// component.ts file
checkMinValue(el: any): boolean {
   console.log(el.model)
   if (el.model >= el.valueAccessor._elementRef?.nativeElement?.min) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

check working example [stackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-rmqwth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)